# Which purchasable houses have access to alchemy / enchanting / smithy / cooking?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I bought the house in Whiterun, only to find out that it doesn't have the option to buy an Enchanting table (though it does have alchemy and access to a full smithy next door).

If I'm going to buy *another* house, I want to make sure it has access to all the crafting stations.  So which houses have which upgrades?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Every home *except* for the house in Whiterun has an Enchanting Table upgrade availiable, as well as the option to procure Alchemical facilities.

If you want a home with a Smithy, you must have the Hearthfire DLC installed. This allows you to buy land and build a house in 3 holds: Falkreath, Morthal, and Danwstar.  There you can build your own smithy.  Other than that, there are no houses with forges in vanilla Skyrim.  Riften and Whiterun offer the most convenient access to forge facilities, though Riften's forge lacks Smelting equipment.

Comment: I favor Morthal's house, [Windstad Manor](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Windstad_Manor), because it has a unique fish farm that you cannot find anywhere else.  I like some of the powerful potions that I can make with fishes.

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to build a Kitchen for it's unique *[oven](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Baking)* crafting station, you can build a Flour mill at [Heljarchen Hall](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Heljarchen_Hall) for more convenient baking.

Comment: Lakeview is the best because it's easy to get and it's best for a beginner of Hearthfire. I like the Lakeview if you built a watchtower. I had to clear the necromancer's lair down the hill because it can belive I'm living near that lair. Winstad has a fisher hatcher which is what I like about Mortal's manor.

Comment: The house you are rewarded with in Raven Rock, Solstheim (Dragonborn DLC) comes with an enchanting table, an alchemy lab, and a full featured smithy (featuring a forge, a workbench, a smelter, a grindstone and a tanning rack)

Answer (score 9):

It seems that every other house has an enchanting table upgrade available for it.  The cheapest of these are for 8000g in Markarth or Riften.

It would appear, however, that Alchemy, Enchanting, and Cooking are the only crafting stations available in any house.  You'll still need to find a blacksmith for everything else.

See [Skyrim Houses wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/House_%28Skyrim%29) for more details.

Comment: Ah, I forgot cooking.  Do all the houses have cooking?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.

Comment: All houses have the availability of basic cooking.  Hearthfire Estates can be upgraded with a Kitchen on the east wing which contains an oven for additional "baking" recipes.  These recipes seem to be uniquely available *only* to Hearthfire Kitchens.

Answer (score 0):

Except for in the dragonborn dlc of course! In that dlc after you start off in solstheim the first town you run into is raven rock. And after you do some investigation on a character I cant remember, they give you a house with all three

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! This does not provide an answer to the question, but rather is a reply to one of the answers. Once you have sufficient [reputation](/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173/295232).